# Want to launch another activity on start up page without using any listener?

Tags: android

Example I have a java class that has sliding menu code which the java name is Leftandright.java.

Then I have a Main_Activity, but without any listener I want the Application to launch at the LeftandRight.java page. How do I do that?

Comment: LeftandRight is Java class or Activity class?

Comment: use delay to start a new activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the starting activity in manifest file, `AndroidManifest.xml`, by declaring that `Activity` as a main activity.

```
<activity
  android:name="com.package.LeftandRight" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Or, you can add this code in `Main_Activity.java` (although this is a **VERY BAD** approach, do not use unless you know what you're doing)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    startActivity(new Intent(this, LeftandRight.class));
}
```

Comment: Heh it's work :P i changed the manifest but i have a problem now, when i launch the program it will show a short android logo page before going to the leftandright activity like show for around 0.05 sec how do I cancel the short android page to go to the leftandright activity straight!